# render out API data in custom format

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm pulling data from an API which i then push it into a variable. From my script below the console reads  like this

```
`1001,1002`
```

But i want it to render out in this format

```
(1001),(1002)
```

JS

```
this.http.post("http://localhost/app/route_list.php", { 'username': this.username}).map(res => res.json()) .subscribe(data => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

  var returned=[];
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

    returned.push(data[i].Route_ID);
    console.log('this is data returned:'+returned)
```

Comment: data.map( function(r){ return "("+r+")"; } ).join(","); The code is in plain javascript. you may have to convert to typescript, which i don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
this.http.post('http://localhost/app/route_list.php', {
    username: this.username
})
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    const result = data
     .map(item => `(${item.Route_ID})`)
     .join(',');

    console.log(result);

    return result;
  })
```

Comment: can you phrase it into my script cos i'm new to typescript?

Comment: so how i do put the results in the console to test what i'm getting

Comment: thanks it worked, what if i want to add more fields for example item.Route_Name, how do i do it.

Comment: Where do you want to add new field? @user6579134

Comment: something like this `(${item.Route_ID})`,`(${item.Route_Name})`

Comment: For this replace `\`(${item.Route_ID})\`` with `\`(${item.Route_ID}),(${item.Route_Name})\`` @user6579134

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155895/discussion-between-user6579134-and-sergei).